# Is it possible to pick and paint dithered in Photoshop?

Tags: color, texture

Most natural colors do not have single colors, but dithered. For example skin:

[image]

It's not just differently shaded pink, but a mixture of pixels of close, but different colors.

Can I pick such color, i.e. remember color statistics and then reproduce it with some brush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try frecuency separation.

It is quite a complex topic. The basic idea is that on one layer you can have the overall color and gradient, and in another layer you have the texture, in this case the dither.

But you can have for example the texture of an orange, the texture of skin, etc. One basic usage of it is retouching imperfections on portrait photography.

Take a look: https://www.google.com/search?q=frequency+separation

Depending on your final goal you could adapt the techniques.